# How to save a file from BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape a website, which so far I am able to scrape but I want to output the file to a text file then from there I want to delete some strings in it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

delete = ['https://', 'http://', 'b\'http://', 'b\'https://']

url = urlopen('https://openphish.com/feed.txt')
bs = BeautifulSoup(url.read(), 'html.parser' )

print(bs.encode('utf_8'))
```

The result is a lot of links, I can show a sample.

"b'https://certain-wrench.000webhostapp.com/auth/signin/details.html\nhttps://sweer-adherence.000webhostapp.com/auth/signin/details.html\n"

UPDATED

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://openphish.com/feed.txt"
    url_get = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')

    with open('url.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
        f_out.write(soup.prettify())

    delete = ["</p>", "</body>", "</html>", "<body>", "<p>", "<html>", "www.", 
    "https://", "http://", "   ", " ", "  "]

    with open(r'C:\Users\v-morisv\Desktop\scripts\url.txt', 'r') as file:
        with open(r'C:\Users\v-morisv\Desktop\scripts\url1.txt', 'w') as 
    file1:
            for line in file:
                for word in delete:
                    line = line.replace(word, "")
                    print(line, end='')
                file1.write(line)
```

This code above works, but I have a problem because I am not getting only the domain I am getting everything after the forwarddash  so it looks like this 
**bofawebplus.webcindario.com/index4.html** and I want to remove "/" and everything after it.

Comment: yeah it is the strings in my delete file. but I also plan on adding this string to delete "/*" because I want to just get the domains. "test.test.com", I just didn't want to add it now because I was afraid the code will be confused with the multiple forward slashes in the links.

Comment: My expected output is test.test.com not https://test.test.com/wp-content/blahblahs/blah   or http://test.test.com/wr-content/blahblahs/blah

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a proper situation using *Regular Expression*.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urlopen('https://openphish.com/feed.txt')
bs = BeautifulSoup(url.read(), 'html.parser' )

import re
domain_list = re.findall(re.compile('http[s]?://([^/]*)/'), bs.text)
print('\n'.join(domain_list))
```

Comment: Can you explain the part after you imported re?

Comment: Also this only does the top domain. and there is 100* domains.

Comment: @BulgarianBoy Yeah I just fixed it, please try it now. And if you want to know more about _Regular Expression_, maybe check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Comment: how do I output this into a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use BeautifulSoup here, it is used for parsing HTML, but the URL being opened is plain text.

Here's a solution that should do what you need. It uses the Python [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) as an easier and more reliable way of extracting the domain name.

This also uses a python `set` to remove duplicate entries, since there were quite a few.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse

feed_list = urlopen('https://openphish.com/feed.txt')

domains = set()
for line in feed_list:
    url = urlparse(line)
    domain = url.netloc.decode('utf-8') # decode from utf-8 to string
    domains.add(domain) # Keep all the domains in the set to remove duplicates

for domain in domains:
    print(domains)
```

Comment: I wanted to use your concept in the script I wrote but I was unable to get it to work. I wanted to just grab the domain so I wouldn't have to use regex  to delete "/" and everything after it.